# rsync runs multiple processes

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rsync

I have 2 backup scripts running using `rsync`. 1st one with only one set of processes visible

The other can end up with 50+ processes. See the screenshot below.

Both jobs are ran through cron and both have a lockfile setup.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-    3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin


LinkDest=/home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday

WeekDay=$(date +%A |tr [A-Z] [a-z])
LogDay=$(date +%F)
lockfile=/var/tmp/backup_daily_v3-lockfile

if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then

        trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

        # do stuff here

echo "$WeekDay"

case $WeekDay in

    monday) 
  echo "Starting monday's backup"
    rsync -avz --delete --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines /home   /home/backup/files/backupdaily/monday --log-  file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily_M_$LogDay.log
        ;;

    tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)
    echo "Starting inc backup : $WeekDay"   
    rsync -avz --exclude backup --exclude virtual_machines --link-dest=$LinkDest /home   /home/backup/files/backupdaily/$WeekDay --log- file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/backup_daily_$LogDay.log
        ;;

    sunday)    exit 0
        ;;
esac

        # clean up after yourself, and release your trap
        rm -f "$lockfile"
        trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
        echo "Lock Exists: $lockfile owned by $(cat $lockfile)"
fi
```

here's the screenshot[image]

Comment: Duplicate question + off-topic for StackOverflow, take a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/547165/why-does-rsync-spawn-multiple-processes-for-me).

Comment: everything seems to be nice, you can have a look at cron logs or run the script multiple times from console to check whether it works fine or not